# A question in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to use the Laplace transform to solve the following equation:

$ y''+16y=(t-3)u_3(t), y(0)=0, y'(0)=1 $

My solution:

So I see the left side of the equation works out to be:

$ s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+16(Y(s)) $

$ s^2 Y(s) - 0s -1 + 16Y(s) $

$ Y(s)[s^2+16] -1 $

now the right side of the equation:

$$(t-3)u_3(t) = \frac{e^{-3s}}s $$

I am unsure if this is right or wrong for the right side of the equation

so then I would get $$ Y(s) = {s+e^{-3s}\over s^3+16s} $$  from here I would just perform Laplace inverse transform

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty (t-3)u(t-3)e^{-st}dt=\int_3^\infty (t-3)e^{-st}dt=\left[(t-3)\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}-\frac{e^{-st}}{s^2}\right]_3^\infty$$
$$\boxed{\mathcal{L}_t[(t-3)u(t-3)]=\frac{e^{-3s}}{s^2}}$$

Comment: ah yes so its s^2 instead of s in the denominator?

Comment: @javahelp yes it is!

Comment: awesome thanks for the help

Comment: What is $u$ and how did it vanish?

Comment: @GuachoPerez $u(t-a)$ is the step function, it is equal to zero if $t<a$ and equal to $1$ if $t>a$

Comment: @GeorgSaliba ohhh, okay, thanks for the quick response